# Binding on change event to dynamically created divs

Tags: html, events, binding

I'm trying to generate divs dynamically (by input) inside another div created dynamically by the user. The problem is that I'm able to generate both divs dynamically, buy the child divs are not going to create any divs by input.

The second one id="usersvmaddnewdivsN" is not going to generate any divs. Can you help me please? Thank you.

(check jsfiddle to understand better)

https://jsfiddle.net/rqebwm59/3/

```
$(function() {
  $(".instancesN").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(".instancesNContainer").empty();
    for (var i = 1; i < value; i++) {
      var block = $("<div>", {
        class: "block"
      });
      $(block).append($("div.instancesNSpecifics").html());
      $(".instancesNContainer").prepend(block);
    }
  });
});

$(function() {
  $("#usersvmaddnewdivsN").change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $(".usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer").empty();
    for (var i = 1; i < value; i++) {
      var block = $("<div>", {
        class: "block"
      });
      $(block).append($("div.usersvmaddnewdivsNSpecifics").html());
      $(".usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer").append(block);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='number' min="1" oninput="validity.valid||(value='1');" value="1" name='instancesN[]' placeholder="Instances #" class='instancesN' class="form-control" />
<div class="instancesNContainer"></div>
<div class='instancesNSpecifics'>
  <input type='number' min="1" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');" name='usersvmaddnewdivsN[]' id='usersvmaddnewdivsN' placeholder="Add new Users" class="form-control" />
</div>
<div class="usersvmaddnewdivsNContainer"></div>
<div class='usersvmaddnewdivsNSpecifics'>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name='usernamevmN[]' id="usernamevmN" placeholder="VM-Username" />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery [events delegation](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) is what you are looking for. You may want to modify second 'change' binding to something like:

`$(".instancesNContainer").on('change', '.usersvmaddnewdivsN', function() { //etc.`

So every dynamically created `.usersvmaddnewdivsN` inside its static parent `.instancesNContainer` will get `change` event automatically bound.

Comment: Nice! There's only one thing. The last div containing "VM-Username" is not working, also is there a way to separate each "VM-Username" parents? (for instance:
1. Add new users = 3 -> I get 3 "VM-Username"
2.Add new users=4 -> I get 4 "VM-Username", etc